# Google Analytics 4 - issue with event listener for buttons

Tags: events, google-analytics

I'm trying to record events for different buttons on our website. Things like: add to cart, shop now & check out.

I noticed that our rep created snippet that looks like this:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.closest('button') && e.target.closest('button').innerText.includes('ADD TO CART')) {
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AW-0000001/EXAMPLE123'
      });
      gtag('event', 'add_to_cart');
    }
    if (e.target.closest('a') && e.target.closest('a').innerText.includes('SHOP NOW')) {
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AW-0000001/EXAMPLE456'
      });
      gtag('event', 'shop_now');
    }
  }, true);
</script>
```

The 'Shop now' portion of this^ script seems to record fine but the 'add to cart' does not. I'm assuming this is because of the 'button' parameter? I'm not sure what the difference is between these two:
-- if (e.target.closest('a')
-- if (e.target.closest('button')

I tried morphing the snippet to this:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.closest('button') && e.target.closest('button').innerText.includes('ADD TO CART')) {
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AW-0000001/EXAMPLE123'
      });
      gtag('event', 'add_to_cart');
    }
    if (e.target.closest('button') && e.target.closest('button').innerText.includes('SHOP NOW')) {
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AW-0000001/EXAMPLE456'
      });
      gtag('event', 'shop_now');
    }
    if (e.target.closest('button') && e.target.closest('button').innerText.includes('CHECK OUT')) {
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AW-0000001/EXAMPLE789'
      });
      gtag('event', 'check_out');
    }
  }, true);
</script>
```

But I don't think it's correct. Maybe it should be this?

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.closest('a') && e.target.closest('a').innerText.includes('ADD TO CART')) {
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AW-0000001/EXAMPLE123'
      });
      gtag('event', 'add_to_cart');
    }
    if (e.target.closest('a') && e.target.closest('a').innerText.includes('SHOP NOW')) {
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AW-0000001/EXAMPLE456'
      });
      gtag('event', 'shop_now');
    }
    if (e.target.closest('a') && e.target.closest('a').innerText.includes('CHECK OUT')) {
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AW-0000001/EXAMPLE789'
      });
      gtag('event', 'check_out');
    }
  }, true);
</script>
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to record all types of button clicks.